# how to see if random paired sample is in dataframe (with conditions)

Tags: r, dataframe

Say I have a `df` like so:

```
T1 <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
T2 <- c("f","g","h","i","j")
score1 <- c(NA,0.01,0.5,0.78,NA)
score2 <- c(1, 2, 3, NA, 6)
df <- data.frame(T1, T2, score1, score2)

df
      T1    T2  score1 score2
1     a     f     NA      1
2     b     g   0.01      2
3     c     h   0.50      3
4     d     i   0.78     NA
5     e     j     NA      6
```

If I want to randomly create new `T1`-`T2` pairs, how can I see if these new pairs are in the `df` but only if `score1` column is not `NA`?
In other words, I randomly sample, say, 2 values from `T1` and `T2`:

```
(l1 <- sample(df$T1, 2))
(l2 <- sample(df$T2, 2))
```

and get:

```
> l1
[1] "c" "d"
> l2
[1] "h" "g"
```

**How would one go about to get the `score2` of the `c-h` and `d-g` pairs from df but only if `score1` is not `NA`?**

My first instinct would be to create a new `df2` without `NAs` in the `score1` column:

```
df2 <- df[which(!is.na(df$score1)), ]
```

Then I can create a new `df` for the new pairs:

```
df3$X1 <- l1
df3$X2 <- l2
df3$X3 <- l2
df3$X4 <- l1

#stack X3 with X1 and X4 with X2 (considering that T1-T2 pair is the same as T2-T1 pair)

df4 <- data.frame(T1 = c(df3[,"X1"], df3[,"X3"]),
                  T2 = c(df3[,"X2"], df3[,"X4"]))
> df4
  T1 T2
1  c  h
2  d  g
3  h  c
4  g  d
```

But I'm missing the last step of how to get see if the paired columns from `df4` match the paired columns in `df2`. In the end, I want to get something like:

```
df
      T1    T2  score1 score2
1     c     h   0.50      3
2     d     g   NA       NA
```

Comment: Do you want `library(dplyr);df %>% filter(!is.na(score1)) %>% mutate(across(T1:T2, sample)) %>% slice_sample(n = 2)`

Comment: You said you don't want rows where `score1` is NA, yet it's in your output. Can you clarify?

Comment: @r2evans sorry for the confusion and delay, your answer below is perfect (so much more elegant too). Thank you!

Comment: what I meant was: the NA in the output is simply because the d-g pair doesn't exist at all in the original df. I don't want to randomly include a sample such as e-j or a-f, because their score1 is NA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a merge/join operation makes sense here:

```r
res <- merge(df, data.frame(T1=l1, T2=l2, found=TRUE), by = c("T1","T2"), all = TRUE)

subset(res, found, select = -found)
#   T1 T2 score1 score2
# 3  c  h    0.5      3
# 4  d  g     NA     NA
```

---

Data

```r
df <- structure(list(T1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), T2 = c("f", "g", "h", "i", "j"), score1 = c(NA, 0.01, 0.5, 0.78, NA), score2 = c(1, 2, 3, NA, 6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
l1 <- c("c", "d"); l2 <- c("h", "g")
```

Comment: thank you, this is it. I just had to include the df2 <- df[which(!is.na(df$score1)), ]
and merge from df2 instead (because i don't want randomly sampled pairs with a score1 NA)

Comment: wait, no. not quite it. i tried with l1 <- c("h", "d"); l2 <- c("c", "g") and I would expect the same result, because I want to treat the order of the pair as invariant (c-h or h-c is the same), but here it returns it as NA because h-c isn't in the original df. Do you know how to address this?

Comment: I didn't see reversing them, sorry. Do you mean `res <- merge(df, data.frame(T1=c(l1, l2), T2=c(l2, l1), found=TRUE), by = c("T1","T2"), all = TRUE)` (then the `subset`)?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```r
set.seed(2022)

(l1 <- sample(df$T1, 2))
#> [1] "d" "c"
(l2 <- sample(df$T2, 2))
#> [1] "h" "i"
mapply(\(x1, x2, data){
  i <- match(x1, data$T1)
  j <- match(x2, data$T2)
  if(any(is.na(c(data$score1[i], data$score1[i])))) {
    NA_real_
  } else {
    sum(c(data$score2[i], -1*data$score2[j]), na.rm = TRUE)
  }
}, l1, l2, MoreArgs = list(data = df))
#>  d  c 
#> -3  3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>